# Ускорить открытие файла в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть событие клика, когда оно срабатывает открывается новая форма в которой есть `RichTextBox`.
Все открывается, только вот медленно... (секунд 5-10) хотелось бы моментально(если это возможно) Использую библиотеку `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`;

Код события:

```
private void Two_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Load_File lf = new Load_File($@"C:\ПУТЬ{(sender as Label).Text}.docx", Encoding.UTF8);
   lf.Show();
}
```

Код формы с `RichTextBox`:

```
public void OpenWord(string fileName)
{
   rtfData.TabStop = false;
   ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();
   Document doc = null;
   object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
   object File = fileName;
   object readOnly = true;
   object isVisible = true;
   try
   {
        doc = app.Documents.Open(ref File, ref missing, ref readOnly,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

       doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
       doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
       rtfData.Paste();
   }
   finally
   {
       if (doc != null)
       {
           doc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
       }

       if (app != null)
       {
           app.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
       }
   }
}
```

Пробовал так (работает так же):

```
public void OpenWord(string fileName)
{
   rtfData.TabStop = false;
   ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();
   Document doc = null;
   object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
   object File = fileName;
   object readOnly = true;
   object isVisible = true;
   try
   {
        doc = app.Documents.Open(ref File, ref missing, ref readOnly,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

       doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
       doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
       IDataObject dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
       rtfData.Rtf = dataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf).ToString();
       app.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show($"Exception: {ex}");
   }
}
```

Comment: Что значит медленно? Медленно это сколько в милисекундах? А сколько времени открывает ворд тот же файл с того же винта? Какя библиотека используется для открытия вордовских файлов? Распиши больше информации, ничего неясно

Comment: @Andrew, дополнил.

Comment: ответ состоит из 2х пунктов: никогда не использовать итероп потому что он сначала открывает процесс ворда, а потом уже дает доступ к данным твоей программе.  И второй пункт - выводить прочитание данных в отдельный поток что бы открытие не блокировало интерфейс. Больше ничем не помогу, разбирайся сам)

Comment: Могу только присоединиться к @Andrew, если есть возможность читать файл без word и interop, читай напрямую, если нужна конвертация в RTF - читай асинхронно. Но уменьшить время запуска word и конвертации файла, если она нужна и реально происходит, можно только улучшая железо, и то незначительно. Можно еще поискать отдельные библиотеки для конвертации, возможно что-то есть в свободном доступе. Можно использовать контрол из DevExpress, который умеет открывать некоторые форматы word без посредников, но DevExpress не бесплатный.

Comment: @rdorn да не, улучшая железо можно значительно ускорить процесс октрывания файла - раз в 7-10) А может и во все 15 повезет. Для этого нужно купить толковый SSD - например Samsung Evo - желательно на m.2 разьем. И еще крупицы можно выудить добавив оперативку с хорошими таймингами. Желательно более старых DDR типов т.к. у них тайминги лучше. Но лучше, все же, оптимизнуть код используя какую-то библиотеку и получить прирост раз в 100-300 да и еще бонусом получить ненадобность установленного офиса на компьютере с запускаемой программой

Comment: @Andrew ну так-то да, но все равно потолок аппаратных улучшений довольно близок, у меня железо хорошее, прям по вашему описанию, все равно word стартует довольно долго если не был уже открыт (все относительно, для меня - долго =) ), пока проверяет кучу всякого хлама типа лицензий, безопасность файла и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

Сейчас новый процесс Word создается каждый раз при открытии нового окна. Но можно создать его один раз и переиспользовать во время работы приложения.

Рассмотрим два варианта:

1. В один момент времени может быть открыт только один документ.
   Можно создать один процесс Word при старте приложения / при открытии окна со списком документов и использовать его для открытия документов.
2. В один момент времени может быть открыто несколько документов.
   Как вариант можно применить паттерн [Объектный пул (object pool)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB). Простой пример реализации есть в этом ответе [Is there a general-purpose object pool for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671711/is-there-a-general-purpose-object-pool-for-net)
   Также нужно предусмотреть максимальное количество открытых процессов, хранящихся в пуле.

При таком подходе нужно обратить внимание на следующие моменты:

1. Обязательное завершение процессов Word при закрытии приложения, иначе они будут копиться в памяти.
2. Перед открытием нового документа в процессе необходимо закрыть уже открытые, как написано в ответе [how to close a running instance of Word document? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445831/how-to-close-a-running-instance-of-word-document-c)

Также предлагаю замерять время выполнения для каждого варианта, например, через стандартный класс [Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0).

**Дополнение:** как и указано в комментариях, использование библиотеки Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word влечет за собой много ограничений и проблем, как с производительностью, так и с зависимостью от установленного Microsoft Word на ПК. Если есть возможность, попробуйте решить задачу с [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)

**И еще одно дополнение**: вопрос на самом деле очень интересный. У нас есть контрол (RichTextBox) и файл формата docx. RichTextBox может открывать файлы формата rtf, но не может открывать docx. Какие варианты можно рассмотреть?

1. Использовать другой контрол, который поддерживает docx. При поверхностном поиске такой функционал получилось найти только в платных библиотеках.
2. Использовать поддерживаемый формат rtf. Действительно ли нужны все возможности docx? Возможно, для требований приложения будет вполне достаточно возможностей форматирования rtf. Открыть такой файл и работать с ним можно и из Microsoft Word.
3. Конвертировать docx в rtf при открытии документа и обратно при сохранении (текущий подход). C помощью OpenXml такую конвертацию выполнить нельзя ([DOCX to RTF without Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837857/docx-to-rtf-without-microsoft-office-interop-word)). Сторонние библиотеки, которые получилось найти, платные, как и в п.1. Поэтому рекомендация выше попробовать решить задачу с помощью OpenXml в данном случае наверное неактуальна.
   В этом случае, несмотря на использование формата docx для сохранения, по факту будут использоваться только возможности формата rtf. Также теоретически могут возникнуть проблемы при конвертации из одного формата в другой (преимущественно из docx в rtf).
4. Открывать документы сразу в Word. Тогда будет реализована полная поддержка формата docx. В этом случае можно также попробовать задействовать основную рекомендацию по использованию существующих процессов.

В итоге нужно проанализировать требования к приложению (где оно будет запускаться, какая нужна производительность и какой формат документов больше подходит для задачи) и по этим требованиям выбрать подходящий вариант.

Comment: В дополнение, можно реализовать нормальное ожидание в UI "подождите, открываю документ (рядом анимация ожидания)", но для этого придется очень аккуратно выделить работу с COM-объектами в отдельный поток, по типу Producer/Consumer. Задача вообще не простая, но реальная.